# typo3 typolink additionalParams for specific target uid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typolink

I'm looking for a way to make the following code depend on which uid the link is created for. Specifically i only want to add additionalParams for typolinks that link to the page with uid 13.

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink {
  additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[news]=|
  additionalParams.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
}
```

it should probably work with `case` or `if`, but i'm stuck.

Comment: Your goal is to create links to news detail? How do you set the id of the news?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi not really. sometimes we want to link to a registration form from within the text. the registration form is at uid 13. all other internal links do not need the `additionalParams`. the code above adds the parameters unconditionally.

Comment: I don't currently know, sorry...

Comment: It would not be the direct, clean way, but in a project, we have used Sebastian's EXT:shortcut_params for a similar use-case. We created a shortcut with the special Parameters and linked via shortcut to the target page. For a few special cases, this might be a solution.

https://github.com/smichaelsen/typo3-shortcut-params